# iOS | Prevent Google Logo from Redirecting to Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-ios-utils

We are using  `pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.9.0'` in our application. We just want to prevent redirection to Google Maps app when user taps on Google Logo in the GoogleMap.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so would violate the Terms of Service:

> (b) Attribution.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. **Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score -1):

Try implemeting something that covers the MapView. (e.g. empty UIImageView)